# Getting 200 response but DB value is not updating - rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, x-editable

I am trying to update my database using the update method and using the x-editable plugin, I am getting response status 200 but when checking the db it is not being updated.

Here is my controller:

```
def update
@verif = Verif.find(params[:App_ID])
respond_to do |format|
  if @verif.update(verif_params)
    format.html { redirect_to @verif, notice: 'data updated'}
    format.json {render :json => {success: true}, status: :ok, location: @verif}
  else
    format.html { render :action => "data" }
    format.json { render json: @verif.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end

private
  def verif_params
    params.permit(:App_ID, :QA_Findings => [])
  end
end
```

application.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';
    $('.findings').editable({
        showbuttons: false,
        send: 'always',
        type: 'text',

        ajaxOptions: {
            type: 'put',
            dataType: 'json'
        },

        success: function(response, newValue){
            if(response.status == 'error');
                return response.msg;
        },
        error: function (response) {
            console.log('fail');
            return 'update failed';
        }

    });
});
```

verif.html.erb

```
<td><a href = "#" class = "findings" data-name="QA_Findings" data-pk="<%= e.App_ID %>" data-value="<%= e.QA_Findings %>" data-url="verif/<%=e.App_ID%>"><%= e.QA_Findings %></a></td>
```

Logs

```
    Processing by StaticPagesController#update as JSON
  Parameters: {"name"=>"QA_Findings", "value"=>"True", "pk"=>"456", "App_ID"=>"456"}
  Verif Load (7.1ms)  SELECT  `data_qa`.* FROM `data_qa` WHERE `data_qa`.`App_ID` = '456' LIMIT 1
   (1.7ms)  BEGIN
   (3.4ms)  COMMIT
Completed 200 OK in 40ms (Views: 1.7ms | ActiveRecord: 12.2ms)
```

TYIA!

Comment: Can you post what's happening in the logs? I'm guessing you'll need to update your `verif_params`

Comment: Response code 200 means your browser successfully fetched page, but your script still can contain logical error. In your example I think you have the problem when run query function to update data. Trace your query text and see sql server logs to find errors

Comment: SELECT is on the logs, but not UPDATE. What did I miss?

Comment: @ToreyHeinz logs posted

Comment: Can you try params.require(:verif).permit(:App_ID, :QA_Findings => []), also  
the columns are generally in lower case for example App_ID would be in app_id

Comment: @gates I got 
ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: verif):   
Also, I did the column naming so i could also follow the naming in my db, is it a bad practice?

Comment: Based on this `Parameters: {"name"=>"QA_Findings", "value"=>"True", "pk"=>"456", "App_ID"=>"456"}` verif_params would look like `{'App_ID' => '456'`}, so when you call `@verif.update(verif_params)` there is nothing to update.

Comment: @ToreyHeinz but, I already included QA_Findings in my strong parameters.

Comment: try update_attributes instead of update

Comment: @Aurb that is true, but in the params you are receiving there is not a QA_Findings key, so something is not getting sent properly.

Comment: @chaitanya, tried update_attributes, still the same. Thanks btw for looking into this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the permit syntax you are using is supposed to be for the mass assignment.

But then as per the parameters you showed

You have to do something like this

```
@verif.update(App_ID: params[:APP_ID))
```

Regarding your `:QA_Findings => []`, it is not getting sent into parameters itself.